# Listener на аппаратную кнопку

Tags: android

Как можно повесить слушатель на активити для нажатия аппаратной кнопки БЭК?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В активити уже есть метод [OnBackPressed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed())(). Просто переопределите его.

Comment: `OnBackPressed()` c 2.1. до - отслеживать нажатие `onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`. хорошая статья http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html

Answer (score 1):

Элементарно:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
    {
            //blah-blah
    }
    else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH)
    {
            //blah-blah
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```